# Huawei Themes Error in dashboard when submitting for design qualification

Tags: huawei-mobile-services, huawei-developers

We want to make theme for the Huawei platform. I am not able to submit for design qualification, Because last 6 months same message show on my dashboard.  I have also attached showing a message on my dashboard.[image]

Answer (score 0):

Please click on  "understood"  button and apply again.

[image]

For detail how to apply Themes qualification, you can check reference link:

https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/distribution/content/settlement-guidance

[image]